# In cathode ray experiment, will cathode run out of electrons after some time?

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, nuclear-physics, atoms, electronics

If we are performing an cathode ray experiment will there be a time when cathode stop sending electrons or run out of electrons, something like that.

Answer (score 0):

No. The cathode is part of a circuit. Current flows around the circuit, while the charge on each component remains (nearly) constant.